# Is "不特定多数" slang for "date more than 1 person at the same time"?

Tags: slang

Is "不特定多数"する a slang term that means to date more than 1 person at the same time? For example, Tanaka-san would date person A on Monday, person B on Wednesday, then person C on Friday and Saturday. "田中くんは不特定多数よくやる人だよね。うらやましいなああ。"

This phrase was used　(by me at least) a long time ago, and my memory is poor. It *seemed* to get my intended meaning across... but I don't remember native speakers saying it, yet its a very weird thing to say. I've no idea how I might have "learned" the phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

不特定多数 is a stiff set phrase typically used in legal or other business-related contexts. I don't think it has a slangy usage like you mentioned, and 不特定多数(を)する doesn't make sense to me. The most common way to say "dating more than one person" is [二股【ふたまた】をかける](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/1786/) (or 三股, 四股, ...).

Comment: awesome. thanks. i'll get that out of my memory.

Answer (score 2):

While we don't normally say "不特定多数する", the word "不特定多数" is [fairly commonly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E4%B8%8D%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E5%A4%9A%E6%95%B0+%E9%96%A2%E4%BF%82&oq=%E4%B8%8D%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E5%A4%9A%E6%95%B0%E3%80%80%E9%96%A2%E4%BF%82&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.1230j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) used to talk of promiscuity or indiscriminateness in romantic/sexual relationships, as in "不特定多数の相手と関係をもつ". So quite possibly you got that expression through this association.

If I were to hear someone say "不特定多数する" I'd probably think (after a moment's pause) it's a grammatical innovation (especially in the mouth of a fluent speaker) or simple error (especially in the mouth of a less-than-fluent speaker), but under the right set of conditions, the intended meaning "date more than 1 person at the same time" may easily get across.